# 2d array how to allow white space in input?

Tags: c++

2d array, how to accept white space in input? in 1d array i think the right code is `cin.getline(array,5)`but in 2d array i cant figure it out what is right parameter.

here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
void display();
char array[2][5];
using namespace std;


int main(){

    for (int x = 0; x < 2; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; ++y) {
            display();
            cout << "Enter a value: ";
            cin>>array[x][y];  //i want to accept space in input. cin.getline(array[x][y],?)
            system("cls");
        }
    }

   display();

}

void display(){

     for(int x = 0; x<2; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y<5; y++){
            cout<<" " <<array[x][y] <<" ";
        }  
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

lastly, how can i limit the input in cin>>? for example it will only allow 1 character input. ty in advance

Comment: Use an array or `std::vector` of `std::string` and then you can just use `std::getline`.

Comment: i am not allowed to use vector. i see, i will just use string. thanks oliver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**how to accept white space in input?**

The problem was with your logic. You were trying to store a `string` or `char*` simply to a char. Even though its a 2D array, it will not work like that. You need either a `char*` or `std::string` for that, something like follows.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void display();
string array[2][5];

int main()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 2; ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; ++y)
        {
            display();
            cout << "Enter a value for ["<<x+1<<"]["<<y+1<<"]: ";
            std::getline(std::cin, array[x][y]);
            system("cls");
        }
    }
   display();
}

void display()
{
     for(int x = 0; x<2; x++)
     {
        for(int y = 0; y<5; y++)
            cout<<" " <<array[x][y] <<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

Hope this was the case, any doubts, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
void display();
char array[2][5];

using namespace std;

int main() {

    for (int x = 0; x < 2; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; ++y) {

            display();
            cout << "Enter a value: ";
            cin>>array[x][y]; 

           if(array[x][y]==" ";
            break;
            system("cls");
        }
    }

    display();
}

void display() {

    for(int x = 0; x<2; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y<5; y++) {
            cout<<" " <<array[x][y] <<" ";
        }  
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```